# Aurelia: Trying to make 2 HTML columns with single array

Tags: html, multiple-columns, aurelia, repeater

I'm having a problem figuring out how to make two equal columns (won't be exactly equal if the array length is odd) out of a single array.

So , and have them in two columns.

Comment: If you can give an example of what you want to do, it will be easier for folks to help. You can clone this to create it https://stackblitz.com/edit/aurelia-javascript?file=index.js

Answer (score 2):

This isn't really a question specific to Aurelia, but I'm guessing the follow-up question would be.

`won't be exactly equal if the array length is odd`

That tells me you want to have this:

`[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]`

And turn it into this:

`[[1, 2], [3, 4], [5, 6]]`

If you want to do this in a repeater, try this:

```
export class PairValueConverter {
    fromView(input) {
        return input.reduce((res, cur, i, arr) {
          if (i % 2 === 0) res.push(arr.slice(i, i + 2));
          return res;
        }, []);
    }
}
```

And then in your html:

```
<div repeat.for="item of items | pair">${item[0]} - ${item[1]}</div>
```

It's better if you put more effort in your question though, show what you've tried, etc. Someone might judge me for answering this :)